# How do I debug an application which is immediately killed when opening it?

Tags: debugging

I have an application that used to work, but randomly stopped working. The problem is I can't debug it because it is immediately killed when opening it. Examples:

```
$ ./the_application
Killed: 9
```

or

```
$ ./the_application | gdb
(gdb) quit
```

Answer (score 2):

When you run `./the_application | gdb`, you're running `the_application` normally and treating its output as commands to gdb.

To debug a program, pass the executableas argument to gdb.

```
gdb the_application
```